# Python xml parsing with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I have below xml file, I would like to extract all the `href`,  I know how to do that, but I want to mark end of each main 'parent' tag with `----`

I need an output like this:

```
xxxx yyyy ----- zzzz tttt ------ wwww qqqqq ssss uuuu oooo pppp ----- mmmm nnnnn ----
```

xml:

```
<root> <parent id1='1111'> <child herf='xxx'/> <child herf ='yyyy'/> </parent> <parent id1='22222'> <child herf='zzzz'/> <child herf ='tttt'/> </parent> <parent id1='33333'> <child herf='wwww'/> <child herf ='qqqqq'/> <parent id1='4444'> <child herf='ssss'/> <child herf ='uuuu'/> </parent> <parent id1='55555'> <child herf='oooo'/> <child herf ='pppp'/> </parent> <parent id1='6666'> <child herf='mmmm'/> <child herf ='nnnnn'/> </parent>
```

This is my code :

```
xml= soupTop.findChildren(recursive=False) for tag in xml: s =tag.findAll("child", {"href" : re.compile(r".*")}) print (s)
```

Comment: Can you post your xml?

Comment: <root>
<parent id1='1111'>
<child herf='xxx'/>
<child herf ='yyyy'/>
</parent>  
<parent id1='22222'>
<child herf='zzzz'/>
<child herf ='tttt'/>
</parent> 
<parent id1='33333'>
<child herf='wwww'/>
<child herf ='qqqqq'/>
<parent id1='4444'>
<child herf='ssss'/>
<child herf ='uuuu'/>
</parent> 
<parent id1='55555'>
<child herf='oooo'/>
<child herf ='pppp'/>
</parent> 
<parent id1='6666'>
<child herf='mmmm'/>
<child herf ='nnnnn'/>
</parent>

Comment: What have you done so far? What code do you need help with?

Comment: this is my code;

Comment: xml= soupTop.findChildren(recursive=False)
for tag in xml:
    s =tag.findAll("child", {"href" : re.compile(r".*")})
    print (s)

Comment: Can you please edit your post instead of posting it in comments?

Comment: I can not see the edit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that your xml is not valid. `<root>` tag is never closed, nor is `<child id1='33333'>`. BS is good at accepting incorrect input, but processing it requires to be very cautious.

That means that I cannot imagine a way to obtain the output you are asking for in the question. What I can do is:

1. assume that each new opening parent tag opens a new sequence of children. That means find all `parent` tags and in each one process only direct children

   ```
   for p in soupTop.findAll('parent'):
       for c in p.children:
           if c.name == 'child':
               print(c['herf'], end =' ')
       print('-----', end = ' ')
   ```

   output is:

   ```
   xxx yyyy ----- zzzz tttt ----- wwww qqqqq ----- ssss uuuu ----- oooo pppp ----- mmmm nnnnn -----
   ```
2. process only highest level parent tags, and in each one recursively find all `child` tags

   ```
   p = soup.find('parent')
   while p is not None:
       for c in p.findAll('child'):
           print(c['herf'], end=' ')
       print('-----', end = ' ')
       p = p.findNextSibling('parent')
   ```

   output is:

   ```
   xxx yyyy ----- zzzz tttt ----- wwww qqqqq ssss uuuu oooo pppp mmmm nnnnn -----
   ```

Comment: @Sabby: If it works, you should accept this answer, or post another one and accept it to make clear that you no longer need help on this question.